# Mining/Crawling/ the web console with phantomjs or something else?

Tags: dom, web-scraping, web-crawler, phantomjs, mining

I am wanting to create an application whose behavior is directly related to that of another web application.  Essentially, there is an application that runs within Gmail that dynamically  interacts with the the interface based on the actions of the user.

The problem I am running into is that I want to make an application that interacts with that web application, but they do not offer an open API.  As such I can't just call the api for the data i need.

When I open the development console in chrome I can see the application running, and the debugging comments that run based on the activity.

Is there any way that I can crawl that dynamic activity using something like PhantomJS to base the activity of another application.

"IF the console says "X" in the command console, run "Z" script in this other application."

I am clearly not an engineer, but want to have an idea if something like this is possible.

A very hacky way to deal with a closed API.  I can't see your code or use it, but if I can watch it work, doesn't it seem logical that I can record that realtime and interact with it in another application?

Comment: Without knowing the website or what content you wish to get an answer is difficult...

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a message forwarding rule on the Gmail account and send the mail from the site being scraped to a POP3 account on your webserver. Everything arriving at this can then be piped into a script designed to extract any relevent links and go fetch the end pages.  Unless we can go take a look at the site in question and see how it is handling requests for information cannot be more helpful.